# HTML datalist with a scrollbar

Tags: html, html-datalist

I am using HTML and trying to make list as shown in the image before. However, by using `datalist` I can't get a scroll bar. Can you please tell me how can I enable scroll bar in datalist. (Note: can't use scripting language in my website to achieve this).

```
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Afghanistan">
  <option value="Aland Islands">
  <option value="Albania">
  <option value="Algeria">
  <option value="American Samoa">
  //Many more countries
  .
  .
  .
  <option value="Zcountry">
</datalist>
```

[image]

Answer (score -8):

How abbout this ?

```
 <label for="country">Country:</label>
    <input type="text" id="country" list="country_list">
    <datalist id="country_list">
      <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
      <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
      <option value="AL">Albania</option>
      <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
      <!-- more -->
    </datalist>
```

Comment: How is that any different from what the OP already has? (OK, you’ve added a `label`, but I don’t suppose that’ll fix the issue?)